# np.polyfit plot with uncertainty on the y in python

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, statistics, polynomials

I have the following dataframe:

```
x      y           error_on_y
1      1.2         0.1
2      0.87        0.23
4      1.12        0.11
5      0.75        0.06
5      0.66        0.15
6      0.98        0.08
7      1.34        0.05
7      2.86        0.12
```

With this frame I want to use a np.polyfit to fit the regression line.
I've fitted the line using:

```
x = np.array(dataframe['x'])
y = np.array(dataframe['y'])

y_err = np.array(dataframe['error_on_y'])

np.polyfit(x,y,deg=1, w=1/y_err, cov=True)
```

However I can't find how to plot this fit with my errors defined in python. So far the only examples of plotting with np.polyfit I found were with fits that did not involve a specified weight.

Does anyone know how I would be able to plot this line? Or does anyone know a link to a descent example? I for one have not been able to find one and I have been looking for quite a while now so any expertise on the matter would be very welcome and much appreciated!

EDIT/Clarification:

when the weight(w) is not defined in the function the polyfit function will return a single vector with the coefficients that minimise the squared error. However when the w is defined another vector is also added:

`np.polyfit(x,y,deg=1, w=1/y_err, cov=True)`

output:

```
(array([0.00097481, 0.82290694]), array([[ 4.75261249e-09, -2.28408710e-07],
    [-2.28408710e-07,  1.41696109e-05]]))
```

EDIT/additional info:

after finding this link(https://peteris.rocks/blog/extrapolate-lines-with-numpy-polyfit/) I found that with a non defined weight the polyfit function only returns the first array. i.e.

```
vector = array([0.00097481, 0.82290694])
```

in the line function y = mx + b then 
 `m =vector[0] and b = vector[1]` . aka m = slope and b = the intercept. This means the additional vector in the example above must be the result of the defined weight in the function.

I am trying to find how I should interpretate/plot this with the weights included :)

POSSIBLE ANSWER:
I've found the following:

```
import numpy as np
new = np.polyfit(x,y,deg=1, w=1/y_err, cov=True)
m, b = new[0]
a,c = new[1][0]
d,e = new[1][1]
m, b, a,c, d,e

for i in range(min(x), max(x)):
    plt.plot(i, i * m + b, 'go')
    plt.plot(i, i * (m+a) + (b+c), 'bo')
    plt.plot(i, i * (m-d) + (b-e), 'ro')

plt.show()
```

In this example I assumed that the first array/vector that is given in

```
(array([0.00097481, 0.82290694]), array([[ 4.75261249e-09, -2.28408710e-07],
        [-2.28408710e-07,  1.41696109e-05]]))
```

Are the coefficients for the fit regression line. The following 2 arrays would be the error on the regression line. This is what I tried and I believe makes sense. It is not definitive though so I'll leave the post open for comments and remarks/ better solutions.

Comment: have a look at [numpy.polyfit from scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) if you haven't already

Comment: Thanks Elliad, I did look at this but it is definately a good link to include in the post!

Answer (score 1):

When you do `np.polyfit(x,y,deg=1, w=1/y_err, cov=True)` you're calculating (among other things) the coefficients of a polynomial. To easily manipulate such coefficients you can create a polynomial object

```
p, mycov = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x,y,deg=1, w=1/y_err, cov=True))
```

and plot it using

```
x_plot = np.linspace(1, 7, 100)
plt.plot(x_plot, p(x_plot))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Yuca. sadly when I try this I get the following error: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2). I think I've found the answer though. I'll put it in the question above

Comment: out of curiosity, did removing the cov parameter fix the issue?

Comment: sorry for the late response. Removing the covariance parameter did resolve the error and plot a regression line. However the regression line will not include the covariance by doing this. Still a good solution though when this is not the aim. I will upvote your answer!

Comment: I would like to but sadly I can't accept this as the entire answer. by doing "p, mycov" we merely store the extra vector in the mycov variable but later we don't plot/interpertate the meaning of this variable/vector. Therefore the answer you provide helps a long way but is I think not a complete answer to the question.

Comment: Interesting since your question is how to plot the regression fit and that's the answer I gave